# How to force CloudFormation to create a new bucket of the similar name if a bucket exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Can someone help me out how can I make a template where the cloudformation automatically creates a new bucket of similar name.
For example if the name of my bucket is myownbucket, can cloudformation create a new bucket automatically with a name myownbucket1 (if there is already a bucket named myownbucket).
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do this with a custom resource. The code that runs within the custom resource would list all existing buckets and work out what an appropriate new bucket name would be. Alternatively, some Infra as Code solutions such as serverless framework and SAM iirc allow you to leave out the bucketname and they auto-generate a unique name for your stack.

Comment: Agree with @jarmod, I'll suggest leaving the bucket name out so CloudFormation can auto-generate one for you. What you can do is give the resource a descriptive enough name and CloudFormation will use that as a prefix. e.g. the following resource will create a bucket like: `<stack-name>-myownbucket-<random-string>`

```
  MyOwnBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

To create or update existing buckets in AWS resource management via cloudformation, You need to have **custom resources** in your cfn.yaml/json.

```
  S3Checking:
    Type: 'Custom::CheckS3Bucket'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CustomResourceS3Function.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref NotifyBucket
```

And CustomResourceS3Function will be look like this

```
 CustomResourceLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
            from __future__ import print_function
            import json
            import boto3
            import cfnresponse

            SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
            FAILED = "FAILED"

            print('Loading function')
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

            def lambda_handler(event, context):
                print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
                responseData={}
                try:
                      print("Request Type:",event['RequestType'])
                      bucket_name=event['ResourceProperties']['Bucket']
                      bucket=event['ResourceProperties']['Bucket']
                      update_delete_buckets(bucket_name)
                      responseData={'Bucket':Bucket}
                      print("Sending response to custom resource")
                    responseStatus = 'SUCCESS'
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Failed to process:', e)
                    responseStatus = 'FAILED'
                    responseData = {'Failure': 'Something bad happened.'}
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, responseStatus, responseData)

            def update_delete_buckets(bucket):
                bucket_obj = s3.Bucket(bucket)
                if bucket_obj.creation_date:
                  print("The bucket exists")
                else:
                   print("The bucket does not exist")
                   s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket)

      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 50
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for the late reply, Thank you so much for this @Rishitosh Guha . I'm actually looking for a function in which if suppose a bucket named "bucket" is created, the cloudformation will look that "bucket" is already created so it will create a bucket name "bucket-version-1" and the same like that, if it will auto create the next versions whenever I run the cloudformation.